# How convert Stream to Image?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I have a method that must resize an Image but this comes with Stream format.
I'm trying to convert this Stream to an Image but I don't know how to do it, because the Visual Studio not allows me to use the `system.Drawing` I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you obviously need some sort of image handling library. You can't use `System.Drawing` simply because it's .NET Framework-specific. It can't be used in Core. However, .NET Core now has `System.Drawing.Common`, which is a API-compatible cross-platform replacement.